# How to append the same variable twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to append the same variable twice but it appears the code only works on the second one.

```
var test=document.createElement('option');               
test.innerHTML='some data';

      $('#data1').append(test);
      $('#data2').append(test);
```

I want to append the variable test twice WITHOUT creating another variable. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If this question has been answered, then please mark one of the answers as answered.

Answer (score 9):

Try putting in same selector like below,

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/mrMva/

```
$('#data1, #data2').append(test);
```

As [**Felix**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12717360/how-to-append-the-same-variable-twice#comment17173514_12717380) pointed out from jQuery docs for [.**append**](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

> *If there is more than one target element, however, cloned copies of the inserted element will be created for each target after the first.*

Comment: ... does jQuery really automatically clone elements when there are multiple locations to append it? I would have never expected that. +1. I guess i just never really looked at it.

Comment: @KevinB: Apparently yes: *If there is more than one target element, however, cloned copies of the inserted element will be created for each target after the first.* - http://api.jquery.com/append/

Answer (score 4):

Clone it:

```
  $('#data1').append(test);
  $('#data2').append(test.cloneNode(true));
```

---

Or just do this, and jQuery will clone it for you:

```
$('#data1, #data2').append(test);
```

Or like this:

```
$("<option>some data</option>").appendTo('#data1, #data2');
```