# jQuery each only outputting code once

Tags: jquery, variables, scope, each

this is driving me nuts. Not sure if it's a problem with scope, but I'm stuck with this one. The idea is, jQuery creates a div elements and gives it a class. Then, inside an `.each()` function, this is inserted after each matched element. I should get this three times, but only get it once. Any idea why?

http://jsfiddle.net/9Gfz2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try cloning the `div` before `insertAfter` like below,

```
ratingContainerShell.clone().insertAfter($this);
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/9Gfz2/1/

Ok, took sometime to find the below in the API docs.

> If an element selected this way is inserted into a single location elsewhere in the DOM, it will be moved after the target (not cloned) and a new set consisting of the inserted element is returned:

http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/

On a side note, `.append` is [known to clone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12717380/297641) when appending the element.

Comment: @Dan It moves the element after the specified selector, don't remember seeing it would clone on its own. Remember there is only one div being created here.